# How did "inferno" enter the English language?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, phrase-origin

The more common and oldest English term to refer to the infernal region is  ***[Hell](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hell)***:

> - Old English hel, helle, "nether world, abode of the dead, infernal regions, place of torment for the wicked after death," from Proto-Germanic *haljo "the underworld".

A foreign term with the same meaning entered the English Laguage centuries later. The term is ***[Inferno](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inferno)*** and its usage appear to be from the works of the medieval poet [Dante Alighieri](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri).

> - ***1834***, "Hell, the infernal regions," from Italian inferno, from Late Latin infernus "Hell," in classical Latin "the lower world". ***The Italian form inferno has been used in English since 1834, via Dante.***

Curiously, the relative adjective ***[infernal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=infernal&allowed_in_frame=0)*** had been known in English for seven centuries before Inferno was used in English:

> - ***late 14c.***, "of or pertaining to the underworld," (ancient Tartarus, the sunless abode of the dead, or the Christian Hell), from Old French enfernal, infernal "of Hell, hellish" (12c.).

(Etymonline)

Dante wrote the "[Devine Comedy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy)"  in the early years of the 14th century, but, for some reason  his "[Inferno](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante))" became popular only in the 19th century.

(Wikipedia)

Questions:

What made Dante's "Inferno" so popular  at the beginning of the 19th century as to enter English usage?

Was it originally a BrE or an AmE thing?

Comment: I'm guessing that many English poets/writers of the era felt is was a clever and poetic term.  But even more than that is that Dante's *Inferno* was a very hot property in the literary world, and everyone was referring to it at every opportunity.

Comment: @HotLicks - yes, but that would have made sense also a century earlier as well as a century later...

Comment: Is this questions about the origin of Inferno or about the popularity of Dante's Inferno? Seems like two questions to me? Or is the second question a subset of the first?

Comment: @Hank - the question, as stated in the title, is about the origin of "inferno" in the English language. Apparently its popularity is related to the widespread study of Dante's Inferno at that time.

Comment: @Josh I think it was the wording and my initial read of it. I understand what your question is now.

Comment: @Josh - When I look at Ngram I see uses of "inferno" going back well into the 1600s, thought largely in Latin/Italian/French texts, from what I can guess.  Folks didn't start writing much about Dante's work in English until around 1800, when academic work began to be done in English.

Comment: @HotLicks The first record the OED has is from 1834 - *T. Medwin Angler in Wales I. 24   The passage to what some, who attribute to Byron a cloven foot, might call his inferno.*

Comment: c1374   Chaucer Troilus & Criseyde iv. 1515 (1543)   *And this on euery god celestial..On euery Nymphe and deite infernal.*

Comment: Latin *infernālis* - of the realms below, infernal;  *infernus* adjective, situated below, subterranean, of the lower regions, whence *infernī* - the shades, *inferna* - the lower regions, and, in later (Christian) use, *infernus* - noun masculine ‘hell’.

Comment: @WS2 - Well, Ngram shows number of uses of "inferno" in English works in the late 1700s, but they all appear to reference Dante's work.  The first use I find of "inferno" with the apparent meaning "blazing fire" is in [1838](https://books.google.com/books?id=bPDWB6gOZrYC&pg=PA271&dq=%22inferno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYzN6P6czRAhUhwVQKHdSOC4A4vgEQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22inferno%22&f=false).

Comment: In my scans through the Ngram references I did find several uses of terms such as "infernae" and "inferno-human" (apparently a favorite term of Horace Walpole, as early as 1793).  But it's not clear that these are rooted in "inferno" vs "infernal" or some such.

Comment: Infernal was already in use...

Comment: The title _Inferno_ is used in a [translation by Joseph Hume](https://books.google.com/books?id=R05DAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22inferno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjohsrOr83RAhVN8WMKHdbeAIgQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22inferno%22&f=false) of the first part of _The Divine Comedy_  published in 1812. And a [translation by Henry Boyd](https://books.google.com/books?id=m1w9AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22inferno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjohsrOr83RAhVN8WMKHdbeAIgQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22inferno%22&f=false) was published in 1785. So Etymology Online is off by at least 49 years on that point.

Comment: And then there is a [translation by Charles Rogers](https://books.google.com/books?id=1ARcAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22inferno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjohsrOr83RAhVN8WMKHdbeAIgQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22inferno%22&f=false), dated 1782, which, like the other two is styled "The Inferno"—in this case, "The Inferno of Dante Translated." It seems very likely that English readers of the late eighteenth century became familiar with _inferno_ (as opposed to _infernal_) through these translations.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Yes, but curiously unlike Paradiso and Purgatorio, Inferno was not translated  to Hell, probably because the were already familiar with "infernal".

Comment: @Sven Yargs "Infernalitie" is recorded in the 16th century OED says *The infernal world and its occupants.1593 T. Nashe Christs Teares   I would haue fought for them, with hell, the diuel, and all infernalitie.* It is stated to be obsolete and a different sense of *infernality* takes over in the 19th* ; which meaning sets it apart from *inferno*.
*The quality of being infernal, or an instance of this; hellishness, diabolicalness; a diabolical act or characteristic.1805   J. Foster Ess. (1844) 256   The Mexican abominations and infernalities have already received from us their epic tribute*

Comment: @WS2- It looks like that they had been looking for the a nominal  from of "infernal" for a long time before "inferno"  established as a commonly accepted term.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [David Lummus, in Dante's Inferno: Critical Reception and Influence,](https://dlcl.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/files_upload/lummus-inferno-influence_1.pdf) it was Romanticism that revived an interest in Dante:

> "Although Dante’s poetry had been read and imitated in
>   the English-speaking world since the generation after his death—for
>   Geoffrey Chaucer (c. 1343-1400) Dante was just as much a model as
>   were Boccaccio and Petrarch—the revival of interest in the Middle
>   Ages that came with romanticism made the Comedy the figurehead for
>   a new kind of visionary poetry. **For English romantic poets like Samuel
>   Taylor Coleridge (1772-1834) and Henry Francis Cary (1772-1844)
>   Dante’s poetry was an example of how Art could represent the totality
>   of human experience, and it was their job to English that Art."

Cary, an Englishman, was apparently best known for his free verse translation which is [here](https://archive.org/stream/DantesInfernoTranslatedByHenryFrancisCaryFromTheOriginalOfDante/Dantes_Inferno#page/n1/mode/2up/search/inferno). I think it was published in 1814, according to Wikipedia.

https://www.britannica.com/biography/Henry-Francis-Cary, a short bio of him.

Comment: So it may have been specific people that initiated the popularity? Because of the romanticism?

Comment: Generally, when great books are translated, people start reading them. The poem's title was not changed: Dante's Inferno. So, there is the word and that's probably what started it.

Comment: The Divine Comedy consists of 3 parts, Paradiso, Purgatorio and Inferno. Only Inferno was adopted.

Comment: The Divina Commedia is in three parts. Only inferno was adopted?? Because the words paradise and purgatory were already in use, surely.